# I want to show that ker f is a normal subgroup of some group $X$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Suppose I have two groups, call them $X$ and $Y$, and I let $f : X \longrightarrow Y$ be a group homomorphism. I want to prove that the ker $f$ is a normal subgroup of $X$. Here is my attempt. Let me know how my proof looks and if I am missing details:

We want to show that $aca^{-1} \in$ Ker $f$, $\forall a \in A$ and $\forall c \in$ Ker $f$.

$f(aca^{-1}) = f(a)f(c)f(a^{-1})$

$= f(a)f(c)f(a)^{-1}$

$= f(a)If(a)^{-1}$ because $c \in$ Ker $f$

$= f(a)f(a)^{-1}$

$= I$

Thus, ker $f$ is a normal subgroup of $X$.

Comment: Actually, "is the kernel of some homomorphism" is one of several possible definitions of "normal subgroup".

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it looks entirely fine. You might want to explicitly state what $I$ means, but the logic is sound.

Comment: So, you mean to say that $I$ is the identity before I start the proof?

Comment: @user91154 Yes, it's always a good idea to define your objects at the beginning.

Comment: After looking at my proof, do I need stars in between everything?

Comment: @user91154 Not unless you really want to. Sometimes it's good to have when there's possible confusion, but it's really clear from context currently.

Answer (score 1):

It looks good, provided that you already know that the preimage of a subgroup is a subgroup. And it can easily be generalized to *The preimage of a normal subgroup of $Y$ is a normal subgroup of $X$.*